# Java GUI append text without removing previous text

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to append some text to a label that already contains some text without replacing the existing text. Using setText() it just replaces the string with the new string, so what method would be appropriate if I wanted to keep the old string while appending another to it?

Comment: how about label.setText(label.getText() + " More text")

Answer (score 4):

take a look at [JLabel.getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29).

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();
myLabel.setText("abc");
myLabel.setText(myLabel.getText() + "def");
System.out.println(myLabel.getText()); // "abcdef"
```